# Permissions error on Send/Receive in Outlook 2007

Tags: windows-vista, microsoft-outlook-2007

I have a Vista machine with Outlook 2007.  When Send/Receive is clicked, on of the email accounts gives an error.  0x80070005 You don't have appropriate permissions to perform this operation.

The other email account in Outlook does not have this problem.  We've talked to the ISP, and it's not a problem with the account.

Attempted to fix by the following:

- Used dcomcnfg to look for permissions
  problems
- Downloaded Office SP2 and all
  available updates
- Checked pst file with scanpst -
  errors were found, but didn't correct
  the problem.
- Ran Microsoft Office Diagnostics -
  nothing found
- Ran a repair on the Office Suite -
  problem still persists.
- Backed up pst files, removed them,
  deleted the accounts and re-created
  the accounts and the problem still
  appeared.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [creating a new mail profile](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/829918) in Outlook.  Best to close Outlook and go into Mail from the Control Panel to do this.  Make sure you create a new PST and not point it to the old one.

Can you replicate the problem with Windows Mail if you try setting the account up in there?  Warning - ensure that you enable the "leave messages on server" option so you can eventually redownload new emails into Outlook when you get it up and running again.

Are you running any antivirus software?  If so, temporarily disable it and any mail scanning features (or uninstall it if it's not too much of a pain to reinstall) and see if you get the same error.  If not, get some and scan your system for nasties.

Try an sfc /scannow (Start | Run | sfc /scannow ) with your Vista install CD in the drive.  Restart and try it again.  Doubt it will help, but it's always a good step to try anyway.